# Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type while reading d_name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directory, dirent.h

I need to check whether file name ends with .config present in a folder. So I'm using below code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main(){
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *dp;
char prnStr[254];

if ((dirp = opendir("D:/New folder/")) == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not open directory!!";
        return;
    }
    if ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        prnStr << dp->d_name;
        size_t findprn = prnStr.str().find(".config");

        if ((int)findprn != -1) {
            cout << "Found .config File!!!!!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "No .config files detected at this time...";
        }
    }
   }
```

Getting error at this line prnStr << dp->d_name; as Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: `prnStr << dp->d_name` makes no sense whatsoever. It's not clear what you think it is supposed to achieve, but whatever it is, it doesn't do that. The same is true of `prnStr.str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `std::ostringstream`. Change `prnStr` to be such an object.

Change the line

```
char prnStr[254];
```

to

```
std::ostringstream prnStr;
```

On a separate note, you are looking for a `.config` file. Maybe you should change the line

```
        cout << "Found .prn File!!!!!";
```

to

```
        cout << "Found .config File!!!!!";
```

and change

```
        cout << "No .prn files detected at this time...";
```

to

```
        cout << "No .config files detected at this time...";
```

Comment: Thanks @R Sahu
If i change prnStr to std::ostringstream then this 2 lines are throwing error 
     prnStr << dp->d_name;
     size_t findprn = prnStr.str().find(".config");
no operator << matches these operands operand types are std::ostringstream << char[260]
can you please help me

Comment: @AlexMathew, what platform and compiler are you using? I am a little concerned that you are using `void main()`. The standard requires you to use `int main()`.

Comment: @AlexMathew Did you perhaps forget `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: @molbdnilo @R Sahu thanks. Error is resolved but i'm not getting file in that directory. I added config file inside directory but d_name is coming ".". So always getting no file found message

Comment: @AlexMathew You're only reading the first directory entry, which is `.` (the current directory itself).

Comment: @molbdnilo so I should loop through it? or any other method?